# Why is initializing C union using "designated initializer" giving random values?

Tags: c, initialization, c99, unions, buffer-overflow

I had a "bug" which I spent quite a while chasing:

```
typedef union {
    struct {
        uint8_t mode: 1;
        uint8_t texture: 4;
        uint8_t blend_mode: 2;
    };
    uint8_t key;    
} RenderKey;
```

Later this union would be initialized (on stack):

```
Buffers buffers[128]; // initialized somewhere else

void Foo(int a, int b)
{
   //C99 style initialization (all the other values should be 0)
   RenderKey rkey = {.blend_mode = 1};      

   //rkey.key would sometimes be >= 128 thus would write out of array bounds
   DoStuffWithBuffer(&buffers[rkey.key]);
}
```

This seemed to indicate that the last bit of the union bitfield wouldn't be initialized. So I fixed it with adding the unused bit:

```
typedef union {
    struct {
        uint8_t mode: 1;
        uint8_t texture: 4;
        uint8_t blend_mode: 2;
        uint8_t unused: 1;
    };
    uint8_t key;    
} RenderKey;
```

This works, but I don't understand **WHY** exactly. 
That random 1 bit comes from the random garbage on stack before, but why isn't the C99 style initialization working here? Because of the `union` and the anonymous `struct`?

This happens on `Clang 3.5` and `tcc`, but not on `gcc 4.9.2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C11 it is stated at §6.7.9 that

> The initialization shall occur in initializer list order, each initializer provided for a particular subobject overriding any previously listed initializer for the same subobject; **all subobjects** that are not initialized explicitly shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.

But the hidden padding bit is not a subobject, it doesn't undergo that constraint because from the anonymous `struct` point of view it doesn't exist, so the compiler is not initializing something that is not a member of the `struct`, which isn't that strange after all.

A similar example would be to have something like

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
    unsigned char foo;
    float value;
} Test;

int main(void) {
    Test test = { .foo = 'a', .value = 1.2f};

    printf("We expect 8 bytes: %zu\n", sizeof(Test));
    printf("We expect 0: %zu\n", (void*)&test.foo - (void*)&test);
    printf("We expect 4: %zu\n", (void*)&test.value - (void*)&test);

    unsigned char* test_ptr = (unsigned char*) &test;

    printf("value of 3rd byte: %d\n", test_ptr[2]);
}
```

What would expect `test_ptr[2]` to be? There are 3 bytes of padding between the two members of the `struct` which are not part of any subobject, initializing them would be a waste of time since in a normal scenario you can't access them.

Comment: I can follow the anonymous `struct` being only 7 bits and as such initializing only those bits. What's making this case confusing is that the variable `key` is there and it's a union.

Comment: @JBeurer: you are not initializing the union through `key`, you are doing it through the `struct`. So the fact that there is an `union` is irrelevant. When you choose to initialize your whole object through the struct then you are "restricting" `RenderKey` to be considered as that `struct` only.

Comment: In other words, when you're initializing `union` you pick the variable you are going to initialize it with. If it was `union {uint8_t a; uint32_t b}` and it was initialized using `a` (and 24 most significant bits of `b` would end up being random) it would be much less confusing of a case.